# Disabled Input Field on Responsive Mode in Chrome

Tags: html, google-chrome

I have a form with Seven fields designed with Yii2. They validation and the input works well on all browsers but the moment i switch to responsive mode using the Developer Tools, Four of those fields stops working (it becomes disabled). It happens majorly on Google Chrome and Internet Explorer. I have tried all i can to resolve this but not hitting a head way. Please guide me on how to resolve this.

An image showing the list of fields is attached[image]

Answer (score 0):

After i tried all possible ways, i first commented out the whole css that was attached and immediately it started working. So i started adding the css one after the other and boom!!! the judas showed up and that was how i discovered that it was just a line of that css that was the cause. 
Found float:left as one of the properties of the input['type=text']. I removed it and works fine now.